# Thicker interior borders compared to outer border

Tags: css, list, border, frame

http://jsfiddle.net/MzqYL/3/

In the example above the border of the frame is thinner than the inner borders.

How can I fix this difference?

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEtio.png

Comment: If you can live with fixed widths then this is a possible solution: http://jsfiddle.net/MzqYL/8/ Your root issue is that each of the `<a/>` elements has a border so where they meet each other, the border is doubled. Out of interest, if you are laying out the data in a tabular format, why not use a table?

Comment: That's because the li's a close together, and each has its own border around it (so 1px+1px = 2px).

Comment: Thanks @dash but when add new li it breaks design: http://jsfiddle.net/MzqYL/14/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I have:

```
body {
    margin: 10px;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-right: 0;
}
ul:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    height: 0;
}

li {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}

/* Styles for Menu Items */
ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #777;
    padding: 5px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}

li > a {
    display: block;
}

ul li a:hover {
    color: #E2144A;
    background: #f9f9f9;
}

/* Hover Styles */
li ul li a {
    padding: 2px 5px;
}

/* Sub Menu Styles */
​
```

#### Some points:

- Please indent code properly, for yours and ours sake.
- What I did is set a **left** and **bottom** border on the `a` elements, and a **top** and **left** border on the `ul` element. This makes a consistent 1px border.
- I use clearfix to give the `ul` height with the floated elements.
- I use `box-sizing: border-box` to make it so that when I set `width: 50%`, it'll be 50%, **including** padding and border (not margin).

Comment: @dash: I usually add it to my reset, along with `* { padding: 0; margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }`

Comment: I'll be sure to try it out in some work I have planned soon - thanks for the tip :-)

Comment: Oops. It's just in Opera. @MadaraUchiha Can you investigate why Opera doesn't have left border. My skills are limited, I tried to find problem but couldn't. If it's Opera's bug I'll report it.

Answer (score 1):

There is how: http://jsfiddle.net/MzqYL/9/

Basic idea is to define border on two sides for inner elements and add missing borders to main wrapper element.

Comment: Thanks, it's working but i think no need to create a new markup as Madara Uchiha.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are stacking the borders so the 1px from the box above + the 1 px from the box below = 2 px. That is why it seems to be thicker.

The way you solve this is by applying different styles to each type of box.
There are 4 types,

1. Normal box (border on left and on top) Style added
2. Boxes on the right (border on the left right and top)
3. Boxes on the bottom (border on the left top and bottom)
4. The one box that is on the bottom right (all 4 borders)

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/MzqYL/10/)

In the example two css classes are added: .right and .last You can just give one box multiple classes `<li><a class="right last">...</a></<li>` so you can apply styles to the list items easily.

Comment: Great, only you didn't post the example :D

Comment: @Madara Uchiha the link to jsfiddle is a the refined example.

Comment: Well, if you look real close, you'd see that I restored that link, and before my edition it wasn't there :)

Comment: Thanks for answer. But I don't want more class, so, for now Uchiha's answer is better.